# python chat client lib

Tags: python, multithreading, chat

I'm trying to write a Python lib that will implement the client side of a certain chat protocol.

After I connect to the server,
I start the main loop where I read from the server and handle received commands and here I need to call a callback function (like `on_message` or `on file_received`, etc).

How should I go about implementing this?
Should a start a new thread for each callback function? As maybe some callbacks will take some time to return and I will timeout.
Also,
If the main loop where I read from the server is in a thread can I write to the socket from another thread(send messages to the server)?
Or is there a better approach?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the select module, or alternately twisted, however select is a bit more portable, and to my mind somewhat more pythonic.

Answer (score 6):

For a python app doing this, I wouldn't use threads.  I would use a framework like [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com).

The docs have examples; [here's a chat example](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/core/documentation/examples/#auto1).

Answer (score 1):

Threads are just an unnecessary complication here and will lead to obscure bugs if you're not familiar with how to use them correctly. [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html) or [asynchat](http://docs.python.org/library/asynchat.html) are simple routes to the same goal, however.